# Подключить PikerView в нужном классе

Tags: xcode, objective-c

Добрый день. У меня проблемка: мне нужно подключить `PikerView` в нужном классе. Я создал `UIView`, но при попытки подключения его в нужный `ViewController` ничего не получаю. (Даже если просто задаю фон `UIView`)

Вот что я делаю в UIView

```
- (id)initWithArray:(NSArray* )Array
{
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
}
```

Вот так подключаю в нужный мне класс.

```
Window *picker = [[Window alloc] initWithArray:tmp];
picker.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height - 216, 320, 216);
[self.view addSubview:picker];
```

Подскажите, что я делаю не так.

Comment: посмотри существует-ли у тебя self.view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 SettingsViewController* settings = [[SettingsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SettingsViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.view addSubview:settings.view];
    [self addChildViewController:settings];
    [settings didMoveToParentViewController:self];
    settings.view.frame = CGRectMake(729, 600, 273, 75);
```

вот и решение

Comment: Кстати, по вашему ответу очень ясно видно, что по тому, как вы сформулировали свой вопрос - ответ на него кем-то кроме вас был в принципе невозможен. Надо стараться ;)

Answer (score 2):

Сложно сказать что-то конкретное сказать по Вашему описанию. Первое, что могу предложить - проверить, назначен ли нужный класс делегатом данного UIPickerView. Ну а второе - ознакомиться с его [документацией](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPickerView_Class/Reference/UIPickerView).